# XSLT To compute start and end time based on duration in seconds

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have a tag which consist of the duration in seconds.

```
<mytag duration="29.473">
```

and I want to use XSLT to transform this into something like the below, where starttime is the current time and endtime is the current time + the duration seconds.

```
<mytag starttime="date:date-time()" endtime="date:date-time() + duration">
```

How can this be achieved?  I've tried `xs:dayTimeDuration` but I'm not sure how to use it and pass in the duration.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to XSLT.   Thanks!

Comment: Date and time handling is vastly different in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. You need to tell us which version you are using, otherwise any answer might be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can just cast `duration` as an `xs:dayTimeDuration`. I'd also recommend making the current dateTime a variable so it's exactly the same in all places that you use it.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<mytag duration="29.473"/>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="currDT" select="current-dateTime()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <mytag starttime="{$currDT}" endtime="{$currDT + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT',@duration,'S'))}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<mytag starttime="2013-05-24T16:15:13.346-06:00"
       endtime="2013-05-24T16:15:42.819-06:00"/>
```

Comment: I'm using xsltproc (http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) and when I use xs:dayTimeDuration I got "xmlXPathCompOpEval: function dayTimeDuration not found".  Is there a better processor with command line to use?  Sorry I'm new to all of this :)

Comment: @user2418898 - xsltproc is limited to XSLT 1.0. I would recommend running Saxon from the command line (java). Let me know if you want me to add an example command line to my answer. The HE version is free: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ Here's a link to the command line docs: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/commandline